# How to get the length of the response from a fetch request?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.
Here is my code:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data: [],
        library:null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,
        filter: ""
        };
       }
   componentDidMount() {
   fetch('/json.bc')
  // Here I want to get the length of my respose 
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
  var Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
   this.setState(state => ({
   ...state,
   data: Maindata
     }), () => {
     this.reorganiseLibrary()
    })
   }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}
  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
  const { filter, perPage , data } = this.state;
  let library = data;
    if (filter !== "") {
      library = library.filter(item =>
      item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
   );
 }

 library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
   this.setState({
   library,
   currentPage: 1,
   maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
 });
};
// Previous Page
  previousPage = () => 
  this.setState(prevState => ({
  currentPage: prevState.currentPage - 1
}));
// Next Page
  nextPage = () =>
   this.setState(prevState => ({
    currentPage: prevState.currentPage + 1
  }));

// handle filter
  handleFilter = evt =>
   this.setState(
     {
     filter: evt.target.value.toLowerCase()
   },
   () => {
     this.reorganiseLibrary();
   }
  );
 // handle per page
  handlePerPage = (evt) =>
   this.setState({
   perPage: evt.target.value 
}, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

 // handle render of library
     renderLibrary = () => {
      const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
       if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div class="tltnodata">no result!</div>;
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
       <input type="hidden" value={item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.hotelid} name="hotelid"/>
   ));
 };

render() {
const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="Main-wrapper">
    <div class="filter_hotelname"><input value={this.state.filter} onChange={this.handleFilter} class="hotelName" /></div>
      <div class="countHotel"> <span class="numbersearch"></span> // Here I want two show the count of items </div>
      <div className="wrapper-data">
          {this.renderLibrary()}
      </div>
      <div id="page-numbers">
          <div class="nexprev">
            {currentPage !== 1 && (
              <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span class="fa-backward"></span></button>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="data_page-info">
          {this.state.currentPage} از {this.state.maxPage}
      </div>
          <div class="nexprev">
            {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
              <button onClick={this.nextPage}><span class="fa-forward"></span></button>
            )}
          </div>

      </div>

  </div>
    );
   }         
  }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

I want to find the length of response from a request with fetch. Also I want to know how to find the count of items that will be shown by  **renderLibrary** . For example in json.bc we have 4 objects I want to show 4 in **numbersearch** span.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fetch API you can find json response item length by running below code snippet. I have also added comment in code as well.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => {
        //below method return promise based response by converting stream object to json
        return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
        //Once succcessful callback return you can find length of number of item
        console.log(json);
        alert("Number of item:"+json.length)
    })
```

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => {
        //below method return promise based response by converting stream object to json
        return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
        //Once succcessful callback return you can find length of number of item
        alert(json.length)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @anomepani. It works .But what about the count of items in `renderLibrary()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length of the data array from the state to distinguish the number of items.

Since arrays start at 0, you will need to increment the count by one. Here's an example snippet below that you can use in your code sample.

```
<div class="countHotel"><span class="numbersearch">{this.state.data && this.state.data.length + 1}</span></div>
```